# How do I run elementary OS on Raspberry Pi 2?

Tags: system-installation

I read that elementary OS supports ARM. I too believe that it should be possible since Ubuntu on which elementary OS is based on supports the Pi. Has any one tried this?

I edited this to ask whether elementary plans to release a special Raspberry Pi Edition and I just stated that currently support is there.